# File, AdmonBursary.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: clickonce

Afer deploying my Windows Application via VS2012 with ClickOnce, I get the following error mesasge when trying to launch setup.exe

```
File, AdmonBursary.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest
```

What amaze is that the application has been running, I just made some modifications and republish and now here I am with the problem.

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All I have done to resolve this issue is to Clean the Entire Solution and then build again.

Hope this help someone.